# manually alter a sm.OLS coefficient

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm running a multivariate regression in statsmodels. However, I would like to manually alter one of the coefficients for an independent variable prior to predicting. How would I go about doing that?

For example, say I train my data on a 2 year time period starting 4 years back. I return coefficients for wind, rain, and sun.

Now say that I train my data on the most recent 2 years of data and again get the coefficients in the regression output.

If I want to use the `wind` coefficient from the first regression output with the `rain` and `sun` coefficients from the second regression, how do I manually change `wind` prior to using `predict`?

EDIT:

Regression code/parameters:

```
model = sm.OLS(y[:train],X[:train]).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X[-test:])
```

Where `X` is `[['rain','sun','wind']]` and `y` is `['growth']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prediction in OLS is just a linear function of the explanatory variables, `x dot params`.

```
my_params = results.params.copy()
my_params[2] = -99999
my_predict = x.dot(my_params)
```

I recommend not changing any numbers directly in the model, because then any inferential results are invalid for the changed model.

If you have known parameters, then you can estimate a restricted model, e.g. with `GLM.fit_constrained`, or add them to the offset in GLM.

Comment: thanks for the reply. as i'm a bit new to this, would you mind explaining the comment regarding the changing of numbers in the model?

Comment: You could do `results.params[2] = -999`, which would change the attribute in the model instance, but then other results would not match up with those changed parameters, and you will get inconsistent results depending which attributes have already been cached or not.

Comment: sorry, one more point of clarification. The .dot I have never seen before - what is that?

Comment: `dot` does matrix multiplication for numpy arrays, `*` uses elementwise in numpy arrays. Now python also has `@` for matrix multiplication. In this case `x` is usually 2-dim and params is 1-dim.